# Mockito/PowerMockito to mock static method in a loop with different instance each time?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a static method that I need to mock using Mockito/PowerMockito

```
Public static Person MyFactory.getPersonObject(Info info)
```

This method is being used in a loop and for each `Person` an `Info` instant is created.

`Info` is a data member of `Person`.

```
For(int i = 0;  i< SIZE; i++) {
Info info = getTheInfo(i);
Person person = MyFactory.getPersonObject(info);
………
………
}
```

My problem is how to work with the `Info` instance each time.
I can’t use `getTheInfo(int)` in my mocking.

This is what I’ve got so far:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyFactory.class);
PowerMockito.when(MyFactory.getPersonObject (Mockito.any(Info.class)).thenReturn( /*Person with its info instance*/);
```

`Mockito.any(Info.class)` should be replaced with the correct `Info` instance in runtime, so probably I’m not using the right method.

Does Mockito/PowerMockito supports it?

Thanks

Comment: is getTheInfo() a private method in same class?

Comment: yes it is like you said

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
   ArgumentCaptor<Info> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Info.class);

    doAnswer(invocation-> {
      Info info = argumentCaptor.getValue();
      /* check for some property of info and based on that return different instances of person object*/
      if(...) {
        return person1
      }
      else if (....) {
        return person2
      }
      ....
    }).when(MyFactory).getPersonObject(argumentCaptor.capture());
```

Comment: I have no way to know which Info fits which person, let's say it changes all the time

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you want to create a Person object yourself in your test class and return it when `MyFactory.getPersonObject` is called?